# What are the "Overlapping Squares" icon in status menu on login screen?

Tags: macos, icon, ios

On El Capitan's login screen the status menu (top right near time) shows an icon of two overlapping squares, one square is to the top left and looks behind the other. 
It doesn't show once I login.
What does this icon represe

Answer (score 1):

Does the icon look like what is in this image?

http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/screen-sharing-messages-app-mac-os-x.jpg

If so it sounds like it would be related to Screen Sharing.

Comment: Yes. That's it. Why would screen share show on login screen?

Comment: That I'm not as sure about. Is Screen Sharing enabled in System Preferences Sharing?

Comment: Nope, screen sharing is not enabled.