# Screen Sharing icon on login screen

Tags: mac, screen-sharing, login-screen

I noticed the Screen Sharing icon when logging in despite it being disabled on my computer. After logging in, it didn't appear in the menu bar.

[image: The Screen Sharing icon, on the login screen]

What could be causing it? I tried enabling and disabling it via the command line but it persists.

```
# Enable Screen Sharing
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist

# Disable Screen Sharing
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist
```

I tried looking for solutions but only found confirmation that this is indeed the Screen Sharing icon.

[What are the "Overlapping Squares" icon in status menu on login screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218798/what-are-the-overlapping-squares-icon-in-status-menu-on-login-screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the culprit, nothing malicious. It's caused by an app called [RetroClip](https://www.realartists.com/retroclip/static/). It enables "Instant Replay" type recording.

Comment: Any idea how to identify the source? I might have the same problem.

Comment: @jukben Sorry, no idea, I found out by trial and error. Try to identify any apps that for some reason need access to the screen is all the advice I can give.